# Adding search parameters to url while using clickTag for HTML5 display ad

Tags: javascript, html

I building out an HTML5 banner/display ad from scratch and would like to have an html form that searches a site by appending parameters to the url. The user will have a keyword and location field and using an html form with the `method="get"`, the url structure will be

```
https://jobs.talbots.com/index.gp?method=cappportal.showPortalSearch&sysLayoutId=123&page=1&keyword=test
```

In order for the ad server to track clicks on the ad, a clickTag query string parameter must be used. This is where I'm having trouble getting the html form to append the search parameters properly.

I have gotten the search to work fine without the use of the clickTag parameter. I have also tried using `javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)` as the form action along with the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clickTag = "https://jobs.talbots.com/index.gp";
    </script>`
```

The parameters seem to fall off using this method. My javascript is not strong enough to write something custom to append the parameters received from the form. Here is documentation the ad server provides: https://dspsupport.basis.net/hc/en-us/articles/115007296827
I'm not sure if it relates to this scenario.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="ad.size" content="width=300,height=250">
    <meta name="click.through" content="ad" />    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Talbots_JobSearch_300x250.css"/>
    <title>Tablots | Search Jobs - 300x250</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clickTag = "https://jobs.talbots.com/index.gp";
    </script>  
</head>
<body>
        <div id="ad" class="wrap">
    <form action="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)" method="get" target="_blank">
        <input id="method" type="hidden" name="method" value="cappportal.showPortalSearch">
        <input id="sysLayoutID" type="hidden" name="sysLayoutID" value="123">  
        <label for="keyword">Keyword:</label> 
        <input id="keyword" type="text" name="keyword"><br>    

      <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
        </div>         
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to use a clickTag query string parameter and also append parameters to the url via the html form. This will render a valid search results page.

In my current version I only have a keyword input but will add a location dropdown after.

Comment: I'm not sure what this clickTag actually is - or let me rephrase - what would a successful query including clickTag look like?

Comment: The query would look just like the full url I included: https://jobs.talbots.com/index.gp?method=cappportal.showPortalSearch&sysLayoutId=123&page=1&keyword=test

Comment: The ad server just needs the variable to be named clickTag to recognize and track the destination url. I just can't figure out how to use this and append the parameters from the form to the destination url with javascript.

Comment: I've looked at the basis.net site and I'm not sure if I'm smarter now. They want you to get the clicktag query string from the URL your above code is running on and prefix this to the URL you want to open in a new window?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `window.open`, you can rely on `target="_blank"` and just use all form input values and a form action to the correct URL.

```
<form action="https://jobs.talbots.com/index.gp" method="get" target="_blank">
        <input id="method" type="hidden" name="method" value="cappportal.showPortalSearch">
        <input id="sysLayoutID" type="hidden" name="sysLayoutID" value="123">  
        <label for="keyword">Keyword:</label> 
        <input id="keyword" type="text" name="keyword"><br>    

      <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

Comment: I have gotten the search to work this way, but I need to use javascript to define a variable named clickTag so that the ad server with track clicks. Therefore, I need to figure out how to append the search parameters from the form using javascript.